# Custom Grid slides with SwiperJS

Tags: slider, swiper.js

Trying to create custom gride slider. Would the following possible on SwiperJS. If yes, please provide me guidelines.

Desktop

[image]

Multiple pictures on each slides with custom grid.

Mobile

[image]

Each picture becomes per slide.